# PHP-Mysql Form Problem for Photo Uploading

Tags: php, mysql, forms, photo-upload

I am new in php and trying to design a system, where i have to upload photo, delete photo from it, and edit photos . i used move_uploaded_file(); to upload photos. and unlink(); to delete photo.I did uploading and deleting photo by form successfully. But Cant find where did i go wrong with the editing.my problem is, when in the edit form,i am not giving any new photos to edit ,mysql table is updating.but when new photos are given, the form doesnt work ... here is what i did..
in the sending part:

```
<?php
            $product=get_product_by_id($_GET['pid']);/*is a function to get product  from database*/         

        ?>
         <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="edit_product.php?pid=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['pid']); ?>" method="post">
            <p>Product name: 
                <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $product['name']?>" id="name" />
            </p>
            <p>Actual Photo:
                <input type="file" name="photo" > 
            </p>
            <p>Thumbnail Photo:
                <input type="file" name="thumb" > 
            </p>
            <p>Visible: 
                <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" /> No
                &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" /> Yes
            </p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Product" />
        </form>
```

recieving part:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $id = mysql_prep($_GET['pid']);
        $name = mysql_prep($_POST['name']);
        $visible = mysql_prep($_POST['visible']);

        if(empty($_POST['photo'])){
            $query = "UPDATE products SET 
                    name = '{$name}', 
                    visible = {$visible} 
                    WHERE id = {$id}"; 
        }
        else{

            $product=get_product_by_id($id);
            //echo $product['photo'];
            $target = "images/products/";
            $target=$target . $product['photo'];
            $target2 = "images/product_thumbs/";
            $target2=$target2 . $product['thumb'];
            unlink($target);
            unlink($target2);

            $photo=$_POST['name'].".jpg";
            $photo = mysql_prep($photo);
            $thumb=$_POST['name']."_thumb.jpg";
            $thumb = mysql_prep($thumb);


            $target = "images/products/"; 
            $target = $target .$name.".jpg";
            $target2 = "images/product_thumbs/"; 
            $target2 = $target2 .$name."_thumb.jpg";

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'], $target2);

           $query = "UPDATE products SET 
                        name = '{$name}', 
                        photo = '{$photo}',
                        thumb = '{$thumb}', 
                        visible = {$visible} 
                        WHERE id = {$id}"; 
        }
 }
```

Comment: what does EDIT PHOTO means? PHP is not Photoshop ) We need more detailed instructions about what you want

Comment: oh i am sorry, it means. replacing the photo.i am sorry, not a native english speaker. dont always know which words to choose!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, problem is in the code:

```
if(empty($_POST['photo'])){
        $query = "UPDATE products SET 
                name = '{$name}', 
                visible = {$visible} 
                WHERE id = {$id}"; 
    }
```

If your form does have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute, your file will go NOT TO $_POST array, but to $_FILES array. So every time you send new file through form to your Update script file goes to $_FILES['photo'] and $_POST['photo'] is always empty. That's why your script just updates the table.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `INSERT INTO` query for new items. Your second query will not do anything if you are submitting a new photo.

Comment: THANKS.BUT HERE I AM REPLACING THE OLD PHOTO.HERE PHOTO IS A "NOT NULL" FIELD IN THE TABLE.SO, AS THIS IS EDIT PAGE.THERE ALWAYS BE A PHOTO.WHAT I AM DOING IS, IF I WANT TO REPLACE THE PHOTO, NEW FILE IS READ, AND UPDATE THE NAME IN THE DB TABLE.IF I DONT WANT TO REPLACE PHOTO,BUT UPDATE OTHER FIELD..THEN KEEP THE OLD PHOTO.AND DO  A UPDATE OPERATION.

Comment: OK, I think I misunderstood the question.